# Know About CloudKit Changes in watchOS 3

Tags: push-notification, watchkit, icloud, cloudkit, watchos-3

Bit of a background: I'm currently working on an app that uses CloudKit in it's WatchKit extension and I was wondering what would be the best way to receive (push) notifications about changes from CloudKit.

In the corresponding iOS app, I use a custom zone subscription to get (silent) push notifications for changes but since the whole CKSubscription API is not available on watchOS, I can't use that.

So, here are my questions:
1) Is there a proposed way of receiving updates from CloudKit? How am I supposed to know that I have to pull changes from my database?
2) If there is a way to know about the changes, how should I download them? The `handle(_:)` method can handle `NSURLSession` but it doesn't seem that I can do some CloudKit operations in there (although Apple mentioned that it's built on top of NSURLSession).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No not really. What I did was a combination of fetching cloud changes every time the watch app enters foreground and using WatchConnectivity to communicate changes from iPhone (that receives iCloud push). However, WatchConnectivity in conjunction with handle(_:) is quite flaky but that's another topic.